# Pass %PROGRAMFILES% environment variable to _access_s

Tags: c++, environment-variables, c++-winrt

I am trying to check for the existence of a file using [_access_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/access-s-waccess-s?view=msvc-170)

```
 errno_t ret = _access_s("%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe", 0); ---> //error, returns 2
 errno_t ret = _access_s("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe", 0); ----> //works fine
```

How to use environment variables in the path for _acces_s method?

Edit: I am looking for a winrt api as this is UWP app I am working on.

Comment: I'd imagine you'll have to resolve the environment variables yourself, they're expanded by the shell, the rest of the windows API doesn't do anything with the shell escape sequences

Comment: ok, so you are suggesting to resolve env variable using something like getenv first and then pass that string to api?

Comment: My question was more about api automatically reolving env variables. But using ExpandEnvironmentStringsA worked. Thanks.

Comment: aah!! How did I miss it! it's a UWP app that's I am working on and I am trying to use win32 api there. That's the reason it's not working. Any suggestion for uwp api please?

Answer (score 1):

Before passing the path to `_access_s` you need to expand the environment variables.

You can use [`ExpandEnvironmentStringsA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-expandenvironmentstringsa) function for that. This function gets a path with environment variables and outputs a path with the variables expanded.

Comment: It's working fine in a console application. But when I am using it in my project, it's giving me an error: `"error C3861: 'ExpandEnvironmentStringsA': identifier not found"` I have included windows.h and also kernel32.lib. I am trying to use this for win8.1 codebase. Anything I might be missing?

Comment: aah!! How did I miss it! it's a UWP app that's I am working on and I am trying to use win32 api there. That's the reason it's not working. Any suggestion for uwp api please?

Comment: [MSDN says it is available for UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-expandenvironmentstringsa)

Comment: Use ``ExpandEnvironmentStringsW`` (i.e. the Unicode version) which is in the UWP umbrella library (``WindowsApp.lib``). If it's missing for you, try moving to a newer Windows SDK release.

Comment: Looking into processenv.h, there is this condition: `#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP)` which is why the API is not accessible to my code. Any workaround for this?